# Double trouble with Python's Ursina 3D engine

Tags: python, ursina-engine

I'm making a weather simulator with Python's Ursina module, but the script crashes with two exceptions.

Console output:

```
C:\Users\x\Desktop\WeatherSim>weathersim.py
Loading modules ... done
Defining functions ... done
Loading 3D engine ... done
Defining clouds ...
 done
Loading clouds ...
01
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\WeatherSim\WeatherSim.py", line 158, in <module>
    Clouds.Load(n)
  File "C:\Users\x\Desktop\WeatherSim\WeatherSim.py", line 146, in Load
    self.Clouds[self.cat[int(id)]].append(load_texture("Assets/Clouds/"+id+".png"))
                                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ursina\texture_importer.py", line 40, in load_texture
    t = Texture(filename.resolve())
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 23, in __init__
    self._texture = loader.loadTexture(Filename.fromOsSpecific(str(value)))
                    ^^^^^^
NameError: name 'loader' is not defined. Did you mean: 'Loader'?
Exception ignored in: <function Texture.__del__ at 0x0000019C62A44360>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\x\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\ursina\texture.py", line 185, in __del__
    del self._cached_image
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'Texture' object has no attribute '_cached_image'

C:\Users\x\Desktop\WeatherSim>
```

The file structure is like this:

```
WeatherSim/
    WeatherSim.py
    Assets/
        Clouds/
            01.png
            02.png
            ...
            99.png
            100.png
```

Here is the code:

```
print("Loading modules ...",end="")
#from rich import print
from contextlib import contextmanager
import sys, os
print(" done")

print("Defining functions ...",end="")
@contextmanager
def no_stdout():
    with open(os.devnull, "w") as devnull:
        old_stdout = sys.stdout
        sys.stdout = devnull
        try:  
            yield
        finally:
            sys.stdout = old_stdout
print(" done")

print("Loading 3D engine ...",end="")
with no_stdout():
    from ursina import *
print(" done")

print("Defining clouds ...")

class _clouds:
    def __init__(self):
        # variables for self.cat list
        cum = "Cumulus"
        nimb = "Nimbus"
        alt = "Alto"
        els = "Else"
        big = "Big"

        self.cat = [None, # catalog of all cloud types for the 100 textures
            cum,
            cum,
            big,
            els,
            alt,
            nimb,
            cum,
            nimb,
            cum,
            cum,
            big,
            cum,
            alt,
            cum,
            big,
            cum,
            cum,
            els,
            nimb,
            big,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            big,
            big,
            big,
            nimb,
            cum,
            nimb,
            big,
            cum,
            cum,
            alt,
            cum,
            alt,
            big,
            alt,
            cum,
            alt,
            cum,
            alt,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            big,
            alt,
            alt,
            nimb,
            cum,
            cum,
            big,
            big,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            nimb,
            alt,
            alt,
            alt,
            els,
            cum,
            alt,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            alt,
            alt,
            cum,
            big,
            alt,
            big,
            cum,
            big,
            cum,
            big,
            cum,
            big,
            els,
            alt,
            big,
            cum,
            cum,
            cum,
            nimb,
            big,
            cum,
            alt,
            els,
            big,
            nimb,
            nimb,
            els,
            cum,
            cum,
            big,
            alt
        ]

        self.Clouds = { # sub-lists will be filled with Texture objects by load_texture()
            "Cumulus": [],
            "Nimbus": [],
            "Alto": [],
            "Else": [],
            "Big": []
        }

    def Load(self,id):
        self.Clouds[self.cat[int(id)]].append(load_texture("Assets/Clouds/"+id+".png"))
    def Load100th(self):
        self.Clouds[self.cat[101]].append(load_texture("Assets/Clouds/100.png"))

Clouds = _clouds()

print(" done")

print("Loading clouds ...")
for x in range(1,100):
    n = ("0"*(2-len(str(x))))+str(x)
    print(n)
    Clouds.Load(n)
Clouds.Load100th()

print(Clouds.Clouds)
```

What is the cause of this double error in Ursina's `texture.py` sub-module?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/pokepetter/ursina/issues/511), it seems the engine needs to be initialized first; this code worked for me:

Replace the `with` statement on line 20 in the question with this:

```
with no_stdout():
    from ursina import *
    app = Ursina()
```